# Removing Launch Screen in Xcode 6.0

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

I've created a browser app, but every time it launches, the LaunchScreen.xib pops up first for a second or so. How can I stop this screen from appearing?

Comment: `LaunchScreen.xib` sounds like a custom view of yours. Have you tried searching for `LaunchScreen` in your code if it is initialized somewhere?

Comment: Nah, it was created with the project when I created a single-view application. I just searched my code for it, however, and it's nowhere to be found in there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Click on you project, in the Info tab you have the line "Launch screen interface file base name"

You can just remove that line.

Comment: I did it, worked fine, but after doing it my app is not full screen in iPhone 6, there is some black region in top and bottom. Can you please help me?

Comment: You can check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796280/black-bars-on-launch-screen-on-iphone5-and-iphone6

Comment: When i remove that file name it doesn't show that launchImage but for that time blank screen is going to appear. How can i set that without black screen directly my app starts

Comment: This crashed my project when  I tried it on latest version of xcode

Comment: @MobileBloke just tried with the latest version of xcode without any problem. Do you have logs ?

Comment: @justa I removed and re-added it a few times and suddenly it started working.  Might have been an Xcode glitch.  Thanks for followup

Comment: according to https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/,  Every app must supply a launch screen.

Comment: Though it might help others, for some of us, this is a disaster. **DON'T USE THIS**

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you can fix this by other way.
You can click project, click General, in App Icons and Launch Images frame, click Launch Screen File then choose Main. Your app will start width main scrren (Main.storyboard)

Comment: I had to uninstall the app and install it again for this to work

Comment: but it displays a black screen for one sec and loads the main screen. Do you have any idea to remove the black screen in beginning of the app?

Answer (score 3):

Go to info.plist and remove value of key "Launch screen interface file base name"

Answer (score 3):

Go to info.plist. In that Launch Screen Interface file builder it was set to Lauchscreen.xib by default.

Don't remove that. If removed, I had a blank black space at the top or bottom of screen. Instead rename the xib file which you want to show first!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6.4 you can just specify Main.storboard as your launch file in the Targets -> App Icons and Launch images -> Launch Screen File.

Comment: HI THERE. THE RIGHT INFO IS JUST HERE :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: XCODE 10.X CHANGING STARTING XIB/STORYBOARD]

To complete what said [Pradeep Banavara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374228/pradeep-banavara) here's visualy where it stood in XCODE .

/!\ DO NOT REMOVE "Launch screen interface file base name" ENTRY OF Info.plist. The screen area will become inappropriate.

Answer (score -1):

**Resolved my issue:**

You can do it by changing the "Launch Screen file" under your target settings on the General tab, Check this link:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/