# UICollectionView doesn't scale with size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionview, size-classes

I'm using a UICollectionView and SizeClasse.
When I build and run the code on a 4-inch device, there is some black space at the bottom and at the top over the status bar.
If I use the Xcode Storyboard Preview, it looks okay.
I have the same problem in the simulator.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you for your answer.

￼[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xovH.png)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot(s)?

Comment: In the storyboard or xib click on document inspector and turn on auto layout and size classes and add a launch screen xib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black bars on launch screen on iPhone5 (and iPhone6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796280/black-bars-on-launch-screen-on-iphone5-and-iphone6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide LaunchImages for all device sizes.

Comment: Instead you can also add a LaunchScreen.storyboard

Comment: @Vasanth I agree it is also possible